# Is there a way to loop through a list and use them individually as an index?

Tags: python

I have two lists, what I'd like to know how to do is use the values in the first list as indexes in the second. Then I can append each iteration to a new list.

```
    out_pass = ['w', 'Q', '4', 'z', 'e', 'h', '8', '9', '!', '@', '3', 'A']
    Lines = [2, 4, 5, 8, 11, 6, 0, 10, 1, 3, 7, 9]
    fin = 0
    fin_pass = []
    while fin < Len(lines)
      fin_pass.append(out_pass[2]) <-- Then 4, 5, 8 etc...
      fin += 1
```

Comment: You say you have two lists, but I think I see only one list... Also please include the desired output.

Comment: I see what you're saying, I'll edit the post!

Comment: Now I think I get it!

Comment: Your first list is syntactically incorrect.  You want quotes around each value maybe?

Comment: You are correct, I just didn't add them for this example. I'll be better in future questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension:

```py
List1 = [2, 4, 5, 8, 11, 6, 0, 10, 1, 3, 7, 9]
output = [List2[x] for x in List1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version of your code that I think does what you want, keeping the structure pretty much the same:

```
out_pass = ['w', 'Q', '4', 'z', 'e', 'h', '8', '9', '!', '@', '3', 'A']
lines = [2, 4, 5, 8, 11, 6, 0, 10, 1, 3, 7, 9]
fin_pass = []
for line in lines:
    fin_pass.append(out_pass[line])
print(fin_pass)
```

Result:

```
['4', 'e', 'h', '!', 'A', '8', 'w', '3', 'Q', 'z', '9', '@']
```

Note: I renamed a few things, but mostly please note that I changed `Lines` to `lines`.  You should capitalize Type names but variable names should always be lowercase.  This is just a convention, but it's one that is quite universal, and not following it will make your code more difficult for others to read and understand.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why I even capitalized there lol. I don't have it that way in my actual program XD. Thanks for the input you guys!! <3

Comment: Cool beans.  Tim's answer is nice.  I didn't notice it until just now.  So you have two equally good answers, I think, one that kept your code structure and one that is more concise.  I would definitely use Tim's version myself.  (but I wouldn't capitalize `List1`, LOL :o) .